# How to get multiple exceptions with NESTJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I would like to know if there are any examples of how to format the returns this way.

```js
{
  "errors": {
    "due_date": [
      "não pode ficar em branco",
      "não pode estar mais que três anos a frente",
      "não pode estar no passado"
    ]
  }
}
```

I currently handle my exceptions this way

```js
if (!contract.title) {
    throw new BadRequestException('Title is a required field');
}
if (contract.phase in Phase === false) {
     throw new BadRequestException(
       'Contract phase informed is invalid or non-existent',
    );
}
```

Grateful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `class-transformer` package and add a global `ValidationPipe` in the `main.ts` file to validate all the request with a body which has corresponding `dto's`

Ref: [How to add Validation to request body in NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation)

Comment: I'm trying to use custom pipes, but in custom logic I can't return multiple errors...

I saw something about exceptionFactory but it didn't seem to be clear how to use it, can you help me?